# How to display Outlook message file body content into RichTextBox in c#.net?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have an outlook message file , converting into stream using below code

```
Stream messageStream = File.Open(MessageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Taking this stream into OutlookStorage.Message object as shown below.

```
OutlookStorage.Message message = new OutlookStorage.Message(messageStream);
```

I am displaying this message object body into RichTextBox.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = message.BodyText;
```

In RichTextBox1 am able to see only Text data wherin images and any formatted data not displaying in richtextbox

My requirement is i want to display message body as it is into Richtextbox whether it might be image , Formatted text or anything.
How can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `message.BodyRTF` instead of `message.BodyText`. To get it displayed in your RichTextBox, use `Rtf`:

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = message.BodyRTF;
```

Comment: thanq daniel now i am able to see formatted data also but images are not displaying. In place of image, Image name is displaying like "Description: cid:image002.png@01CD86A2.E62E9990" . How can i display image instead of image name?

Comment: Mostly, images in E-Mails are simply attachments. Try finding an attachment with that name and display it at the location where currently the name is displayed.

Comment: If u dont mind do you have any sample code for implementing the same